# Fade out objects WITHOUT use of materials

Tags: animation, objects, transparency

So I have a lot of objects with similar animations, but I want each one to fade out at a different time. I already have a lot of materials, so I don't want to make the list that much longer. Is there any way to fade out a specific object without use of materials? Thanks!

Comment: BI or cycles? I think it will need to be material related - a driver for transparency. BI may need to be all same material fade together but cycles should be able to get by object.

Comment: okay, how about Cycles? I can do it in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using render layers and compositing.  Much simpler to use materials though, IMHO. I think the results are better too.

Answer (score 2):

When you create your material, just add a transparency node and mix node. You don't need more materials, just add the shaders and key frame the transparency with the mix node. You can group them and reuse also to save time. That's for Cycles. If you use BI, just key frame the alpha in the output node of your material.

Comment: But you can't do this at different times for different objects without multiple materials (as the OP said in the question).

Comment: Thanks the suggestion for transparency node and mix node really helped me. I had made a mistake that my material was used by other objects, so I had to create new materials each time I needed a fade out, but it worked!